# PC bluescreen when enabling adb on phone connected to PC via USB

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, 6.0-marshmallow, cyanogen-os

I'm using Cyanogenmod 13 Nightly (Android 6.0.1) for LG G3 Beat and i tried to use adb but as soon as I enabled adb on phone the bluescreen on pc (Windows 10) shows up saying SYSTEM_THREAD_EXPCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED (lgandnetmodem64.sys)

If you need information let me know

Comment: I don't think that the phone is responsible here. Has that happened before with this computer?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall LG drivers and let Windows download and install himself.
It fixed blue for me.

Comment: Sounds like a bad answer but actually very true. I have the same phone and same CM13, and uninstalling LG's driver gets rid of bluescreen. Just make sure you reinstall it when you need to reflash the phone in Download Mode etc.